# How to set isolation to SERIALIZABLE DEFERRABLE for a whole Postgresql database?

Tags: transaction, postgresql-9.2, configuration, isolation-level

I think read somewhere that it was possible to configure a Postgresql database to force all transactions to be SERIALIZABLE, but I can't find that document anymore.

In fact, I would like to force the isolation level of my database to SERIALIZABLE DEFERRABLE. Is this possible at all? If yes, how?

Comment: I have never heard of such isolation level. Read about **[Postgres isolation levels](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/transaction-iso.html)**. The strictest (highest) level is the `Serializable`.

Comment: You can only do it at session level because DB level makes no sense. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-set-transaction.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not possible

Comment: @GrumpyPhil That's not accurate, you _can_. You probably shouldn't, though.

Comment: @CraigRinger Why not?  Serious question.

Comment: @Gracchus Some apps may assume the default of `READ COMMITTED`, so they might not cope with `SERIALIZABLE` tx aborts. Bad coding, but not uncommon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `SERIALIZABLE` as the default isolation level in `postgresql.conf`:

```
default_transaction_isolation = 'serializable'
```

This may confuse clients that assume `READ COMMITTED` isolation, so IMO it's better to set it explicitly in your sessions.

As for the rest, [per the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-transaction.html):

> The `DEFERRABLE` transaction property has no effect unless the transaction is also `SERIALIZABLE` and `READ ONLY`

... and given the properties of such transactions, I find it hard to imagine you wanting to make it the default. Are you perhaps confusing it with [`SET CONSTRAINTS DEFERRED`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-constraints.html)?

You can make transactions read-only and deferrable by default with:

```
transaction_read_only = on
transaction_deferrable = on
```

in `postgresql.conf` but it's really a rather bad idea. Instead, just use an appropriate `BEGIN`, or `SET TRANSACTION` in your session before your first "real" SQL statement.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your feedback. I was interested in DEFERRABLE to avoid serialization failures, but may be I am overshooting here.

Comment: Setting the default isolation level to serializable implies discipline and extra work but it pays off (read the end of https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html). If the question is slightly modified to the properties of a specific transaction, it may make more sense: `The DEFERRABLE transaction property has no effect unless the transaction is also SERIALIZABLE and READ ONLY.` From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-set-transaction.html

Comment: @PabloAdames In general, it's a good idea to induce random failures in your app's SQL, whether using `SERIALIZABLE` or not. Adding random failures during commit processing is usually particularly enlightening. But there are corner cases where logic will be correct for `READ COMMITTED` that would be incorrect in `SERIALIZABLE` isolation; some careful analysis is usually needed before changing it.